# Good algorithm for rotating assignments from day to night shift

Tags: php, algorithm, logic, hungarian-algorithm

I am working on a variation of the assignment problem. Previously, I used the hungarian algorithm to determine what the best assignments would be for a morning shift. It takes into consideration whether the employees are trained, and how recently they were at that position to make ideal assignments.

The issue is that I need to make another program to perform "rotations". That is, make assignments for our night shift based on the day shift ones. If our employees are working a double shift, we like to make sure they are on a different position for the night shift. Also, if someone is working a day shift, we like to fill their position at night with someone coming in for a night shift for ease switching the two employees.

I feel like this could be achieved with some variation of a min-flow problem but I was curious if anyone knew of an algorithm or strategy to best solve this problem of creating night assignments through a rotation.

To clarify what I mean by rotation, assume there are four positions: Cashier, Bagger, Greeter and Shift Leader. For the morning shift Abe is the Cashier, Ben is the Bagger, Cathy is the Greeter and Dale is the Shift Leader. All are working doubles except for Dale who is only working the morning shift.

At night, Edward is the only employee coming in, so he will replace the only day shift (Dale) as Shift Leader (assuming he knows that position of course).

That leaves Abe, Ben and Cathy to be rotated. Assuming they knew the positions, it could be something as simple as Ben being moved to Cashier, Cathy being moved to Bagger, and Abe being moved to Greeter.

This is just an example of course. Trainings and other factors come up. It is perfectly fine for trainings to be generated, but ideally it would be the minimum possible.

Comment: Where's the code you need help with?

Comment: Well the code is fairly large for the day shift generator. I was more asking if there's an algorithm well suited for rotating assignments as opposed to just the typical assignment problem.

Comment: It's pretty easy to reach the limits of what one can achieve by solving a totally unimodular linear program (e.g., what the Hungarian algorithm does). You may need to look at something like [constraint programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming).

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 your username had me laughing...ha ha